# Manual routes and "Couldn't find User with id=new" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create routes manually for my users model ( not with "`resource: users`"),

So in `routes.rb` :

```
get '/users/:id', to: 'users#show', as: 'user'
get '/users/new', to: 'users#new', as: 'new_user'
```

But when I'm trying to go to `/users/new` 
i get `"Couldn't find User with id=new"`.

I do understand why it happens, but I want to find way to allow it as is (without changing one of the paths). how does it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of routes is important.  Because you've defined your `show` route before the `new` route, the `show` action is getting executed with `id` as `new`.

Swap the position of the two routes:

```
get '/users/new', to: 'users#new', as: 'new_user'
get '/users/:id', to: 'users#show', as: 'user'
```

Comment: @David, the error must be different.  What is the error?

Comment: Thanks @vee, You right. But one more thing.. I also have in `routes.rb`  `post '/users/:id', to: 'users#create'` and now I get new error: `No route matches [POST] "/users"` when trying to create new user. In my controller:   `def create
    @user = User.new params[:user]
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      redirect_to new_user_path
    end
  end`

Comment: Shouldn't `users/:id` be a `put` request to `update` action?  Because you don't have a user id in `new` action, your `create` action is not going to get called.  You could update your `post` route to `post '/users', to: users#create`, this should fix the error.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your routes as below:

```
get    '/users',          to: 'users#index'
post   '/users',          to: 'users#create'
get    '/users/new',      to: 'users#new',  as: 'new_user'
get    '/users/:id/edit', to: 'users#edit', as: 'edit_user'
get    '/users/:id',      to: 'users#show', as: 'user'
put    '/users/:id',      to: 'users#update'
delete '/users/:id',      to: 'users#destroy'
```

As long as `/users/new`(new user path) route is defined before `/users/:id`(show user path). Rails router would route them properly.