# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Contact with id=new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, routes

I can't figure out why ActiveRecord is looking for the id='new' in my ContactsController!! Please help this is my first exercise with Ruby on Rails.  All my other routes work but my `get "contacts/new"` route.  Im not sure how this is but, when I click on links in my index page the show route/page works correctly but when I try creating a new contact, my new route doesn't work and it says the error is in my show method at the very bottom of the controller.  Please help, I'm new to using the Rails framework.

**Routes.rb**

```
RailsPortfolio::Application.routes.draw do   

get "contacts" => 'contacts#index', :as => "contact_list"

get "contacts/:id" => 'contacts#show', :as => "contact"

get "contacts/new" => 'contacts#new', :as => "contact_new"

get "contacts/:id/edit" => 'contact#edit', :as => "contact_edit"

post "contacts" => 'contacts#create'

put "contacts/:id" => 'contacts#update'

end
```

**contacts_controller.rb**

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @contacts = Contact.all
  end

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  binding.pry

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])

    if @contact.save
      redirect_to contact_list_path
    else
     render "new"
    end
 end

  def edit
    @existing_contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @existing_contact = Contact.find(params[:id])

    if @existing_contact.update_attributes(params[:contact])
      redirect_to contact_list_path(@existing_contact.id)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def show
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
  end


end
```

Comment: `resources :contacts` is enough in your routes

Comment: In the routes file you can use the shorter version for all the routes e.g. resources :contacts

Comment: Thanks @nithin my instructor hasn't taught us the resources directive yet for CRUD operations.  Not sure why yet, but I'll remember it in the future. The guy below solved my issue for the time being. Just needed to move my show route to the bottom.

Comment: @bigREDcode okies, you can accept an answer that solved your prob.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manual routes and "Couldn't find User with id=new" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312322/manual-routes-and-couldnt-find-user-with-id-new-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Show**

Simply, the error is caused because you've defined your `:show` route before your `:new`:

```
get "contacts/:id" => 'contacts#show', :as => "contact"
get "contacts/new" => 'contacts#new', :as => "contact_new"
```

Because the `show` action is designed to capture any routes with the structure of `contacts/:id`, if you send a request to `contacts/new`, it's going to consider it part of the `show` action

---

**Resources**

You need to use the [`resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) directive in your routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :contacts
```

This is important for two reasons. The first is that it automatically creates the following resourceful routes for you:

[image]

Of course, this will resolve the conflict you have with your `show` and `new` actions by providing a "canned" set of routes for your controller.

However, there is another & more important reason to use this process - *object* orientation. I write this a lot because I think it's important for Rails devs to grasp -- Rails / Ruby is [object-orientated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

[Object Orientation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) basically means that your entire application (and flow) should be designed around the various *objects* you want to include in your application. Without going into too much detail, the bottom line is that you need to ensure you are building your routes, controllers & models around specific *objects*, which is why the `resources` is so important

Comment: Thank you @Rich I saw using the resources directive as the solution in a earlier question but since my instructor had not gone over using the resources directive yet for CRUD operations I wasn't sure on the approach and it actually broke my code more. It was just the order of how my routes were just like you said.  Sorry I can't upvote your answer, yet!

Answer (score 0):

The two routes below are conflict.

```
get "contacts/:id" => 'contacts#show', :as => "contact"

get "contacts/new" => 'contacts#new', :as => "contact_new"
```

`new` will be treated as `:id`, matched by the first route.

You'd better use resourceful route, it will be much simpler.

```
resources :contacts
```